# Is there a way to programmatically generate an ovf file that can be used to kickstart an iso image on boot?

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, vmware, virtualbox

Similar to genisofs I want to be able to run a command on a box with minimal additional services and create an ovf and associated data files that reference an iso image and can be used to kickstart a set of rpms.

The docs from the dmtf revolve around either converting an existing vm to ovf or building one using their software package inventory.

http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1/dsp8023.xsd

- DiskSection_Type doesn't REALLY cover the meanings to possible settings
- OperatingSystem doesn't REALLY cover the meanings to everything I need to know
- How do I put in an iso image and force the bios to boot it?

So, this touted app from way back when open-ovf was the answer.  However, its page on sourceforge has had all the code removed and there are no downloads.

I can probably use some Java schema to class tool to create a decent editor, but I'd like to understand WHAT I am editing before I spend a bunch of time on it.

http://www.vmware.com/products/studio/overview.html

- This seems to be interested in building a device within a VM and having a eclipse front-end for it.
- The solution given is based on upgrades through replacement of the vm and not in-place upgrades which runs contrary to legacy code and is IMO bad practice for SOME situations.

Other sources that have failed me:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-open-virtualization-format-toolkit/ -- speaks of open-ovf
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-ovf/ - Was supposed to be some sort of big deal group project the last time I looked into this issue (5 years ago).  It has no downloads, no code, and 5 developers.
- https://blogs.oracle.com/VirtualGuru/entry/ovf_open_virtualization_format_standard - projects listed here are either old, covered by this question, or involve converting an existing vm to ovf.
- ovftool - It can validate a generated ovf file.

I'll comment as I find more and continue to play, but I have noticed a lack of questions on the subject of what is supposed to be a fairly common format for sharing virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [this document](http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0243_2.0.0.pdf) seems pretty exhaustive and appears to be fairly recent (January, 2013)

Comment: Thanks, this is much closer to what I am seeking.  Plus this shows signs of actual activity.  However, the new xsd is a 404 (http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/2/dsp8023.xsd) as of this comment.

Comment: So it seems. There is an updated XSD at http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1/dsp8023_1.1.xsd but I don't know if that's useful for you.